# Access to a value within the span tag

Tags: javascript, html

I'm trying to modify [this range slider](https://codepen.io/thelifemgmt/pen/CeLqA).
Since I have to incorporate this slider in another file I need to understand how it works. 
In particular I would like to know where the code returns the selected year.

I tried adding these prints but it doesn't print the correct year.

```
var rangeSlider = function() {
  var slider = $('.range-slider');
  var range = $('.range-slider__range');
  var value = $('.range-slider__value');

  // added print
  console.log(value);

  slider.each(function() {
    value.each(function() {
      var value = $(this).prev().attr('value');
      $(this).html(value);

      // added print
      console.log(value);
      console.log(value.innerHMTL);
      console.log(value.innerText);
    });

    range.on('input', function() {
      $(this).next(value).html(this.value);
    });
  });
};

rangeSlider();
```

Looking on Chrome, I see that the value being edited is in `span`.
[image]
I can't access to that value. How can I do that?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The content of an element can be accessed using `text()` method. For example:

```
$('#your_element').text();
```

Answer (score 0):

You may try naming each input (e.g. adding `id="Slider_1"`) and then using JQUERY retrieve or set the value.